# VBA Appactivate function works at first, but stops at second round

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I created a VBA code to automate my work in SAP. It has a Do While cycle and at first round it runs smoothly.
But at the second round the Appactivate function can't activate the SAP Window anymore.
It gives Runtime error '5' message.

```
Do While Sheets("LCS pofák").Range("G" & sor) = "1"

AppActivate "Excel" 
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Sheets("LCS pofák").Range("N" & sor).Copy
AppActivate "SAP Window name"                          '- This function stops at second round
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    SendKeys "{F6}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    SendKeys "^v"            
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    SendKeys "{DOWN 4}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "^a{DEL}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "A{ENTER}"                  
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
AppActivate "Excel" 
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Sheets("LCS pofák").Range("AH" & sor) = "Gyeszk módosítva"
    Worksheets("LCS pofák").Range("P" & sor).Copy
AppActivate "SAP Window name" 
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "{DOWN 5}{TAB}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    SendKeys "^v"                   
    SendKeys "{F3}"
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

sor = sor + 1

Loop
```

After the code stops I tried out a test. If I run the program below it gives the same message error No. 5, even if I see the Window on my screen.

```
Sub test()
    AppActivate "SAP Window Name" 
End Sub
```

If I go back to the SAP open screen and run the code again it runs the first round and stops at the second round again.
It seems to me that the Appactivate loses control over SAP after a while.
Any idea how to solve this issue? And why it can't activate SAP anymore?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AppActivate` searches for the exact title of a window. Does that change?

Comment: You're using a lot of SendKeys commands there.  Do you touch your keyboard while that code is running, does anyone else touch the keyboard?  Is there a slight chance that a passing wind could touch the keyboard?  Just trying to point out that SendKeys can easily muck up.  Do you have SAP Analysis Add-In installed in Excel?

Comment: @FunThomas , thank you that was the solution! I only used the beginning of the window title. I inserted the exact title and works perfectly. Thank you again!